# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(n+\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{n-2}{3}+\dots+\frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}-\log(n!)\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to determine the limit of the following sequence

$$x_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(n+\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{n-2}{3}+\dots+\frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}-\log(n!)\right)$$

From the foregoing, consider

$$n+\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{n-2}{3}+\dots+\frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+1-k}{k}$$

Also try to consider Stirling's approximation, so you would have to find the limit of
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(\sqrt{2πn}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)$$

I don't know if my previous statement is completely true, besides, from this expression it is difficult for me to find the requested limit.

Any help please?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+1-k}{k}=(n+1)H_n-n$, where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ - harmonic number. Using the asymptotics of $H_n=\ln n+\gamma+O(\frac{1}{n})$ you can find the desired limit   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: You are missing an $o(1)$. Replacing the $\log(n!)$ with Stirling approximation you need to acknowledge the error: $\log(n!) = \log(\sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n) + o(1)$

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) with $a_n:=nx_n,\,b_n:=n$.

Comment: Well, it seems that it would be convenient for me to evaluate the limit of $\frac{1}{n}((n+1)(\log(n)+\gamma)-n-(n\log(n) - n))$. However, I can't find an answer that reassures me, any help for the calculation of this last limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the Stolz-Cesàro theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)}{n}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \left(\frac{n+2-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)}{(n+1)-n}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}+\frac1k-\log(k)\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k+ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k-\log(n+1)\\
&=&\gamma
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 8):

Let $x_n$ be the sequence given by

$$\begin{align}
x_n&=\frac1n \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n+1-k}{k}-\log(k)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1n \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac nk+\frac1k-1-\log(k)\right)\\\\
&=-1+\underbrace{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k}_{\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty} +\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k-\log(n)}_{\to \gamma\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty}-\underbrace{\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k/n)}_{\to -1\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty}\tag1 
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\gamma$$

Comment: The last term should be $-\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log \left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right)$.

Comment: @Zerox It is so.